# Adjust Cursor/Insertion Point Blink Rate in macOS 14 Sonoma

Tags: macos, cursor, sonoma

Since the revamp of the cursor/insertion point in macOS 14 Sonoma, it is no longer possible to change the blink rate via the terminal commands:

```
defaults write -g NSTextInsertionPointBlinkPeriodOn -float 1000000000

defaults write -g NSTextInsertionPointBlinkPeriodOff -float 0
```

This is highly distracting to me when typing. Is there any way to disable blinking again?